# Loading a Qt app in same process as non-Qt app breaks non-Qt app's tooltips

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

I have a Qt application wrapped up inside a DLL for plugging into 3rd party applications. When those 3rd party applications start the Qt application, the toolbar tooltips in the 3rd party applications stop working. As soon as I close the Qt application, they work again.

I recreated the problem in Visual Studio by creating a non-Qt executable (in this case an MFC MDI application with out-of-the-box settings), and a Qt Application (which I changed to a DLL). I added a menu item to the non-Qt executable, and handled the event as follows:

```
void MFCApp::OnFileLaunch()
{
   QtApp qtApp;
   qtApp.Launch();
}
```

The QtApp class doesn't expose the Qt API at all, and Launch() is implemented as follows:

```
int QtApp::Launch()
{
   int argc = 0;
   char *argv = 0;
   QApplication a(argc, &argv);
   MyMainWindow w;
   w.show();
   return a.exec();
}
```

The non-Qt application remains fully responsive while the Qt application is displayed, apart from the toolbar tooltips (and also keyboard shortcuts such as Ctrl A for Select All).

I suspect this is might be a Qt bug, but just wanted to check anyway in case it's my Launch code that's wrong.

I'm using Qt 4.5.2 by the way.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what it's worth, I ended up having to put the Qt DLL on its own separate event loop. The Qt DLL has a small API that the host application can call to transfer data across, and I just switched threads on entry so that only the thread that owns the Qt event loop works inside the Qt DLL.

Answer (score 0):

Don't do that. QApplication needs to be the one and only event loop in the process to work correctly.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Other than separate processes, I'm not sure I have much choice do I? I can't change the 3rd party applications and the Qt DLL needs exactly 1 QApplication object. I agree that it's a can of worms, but it all seems to work for just about all other events in the 3rd party application. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer lies in the QAbstractEventDispatcher class, whose documentation says:

> QAbstractEventDispatcher also allows the integration of an external event loop with the Qt event loop. For example, the Motif Extension Qt Solution includes a reimplementation of QAbstractEventDispatcher that merges Qt and Motif events together.

I'll look into this. Thanks.